# Keyboard layout changes but when I type I still get the original layout

Tags: 18.04, keyboard-layout, language-support, input-language

I have an Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS and I want to have a second keyboard (Persian) on it.

I've installed Persian keyboard and it is configured as an input source.

[image: Region & Language settings]

Now I can change the keyboard and when I click on *show keyboard layout* it is correct

[image: Keyboard layout image]

**The problem is**: when I change my keyboard to Persian **it still types English** although the keyboard layout is Persian!

What is wrong here? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Logging out should do it, no need to reboot.

Answer (score 1):

It needs rebooting.
I rebooted and the problem solved.